# Condensing multiple OR conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to delete multiple IDs from a table and unfortunately the 'I' ids are scattered everywhere throughout the columns.

Is there any way to condense this type of query?

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE 
  I1 = 1 OR I2 = 1 OR I3 = 1 OR I4 = 1 OR I5 = 1 OR 
  I6 = 1 OR I7 = 1 OR R1 = 1 OR R2 = 1 OR R3 = 1;
```

Table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `recipes`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `recipes` (
  `ID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `I1` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `I2` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `I3` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `I4` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `I5` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `I6` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `I7` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `I8` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `R1` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `R2` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `R3` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3500 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=79;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: Can you share the table structure and sample data?

Comment: Does the query work? What is your specific objection to it?

Comment: It works of course, just cumbersome. I can use excel and concatenate, then port to workbench, but for future reference I'm looking for something more concise.

Comment: This is a mess; a terrible place to start from. Would it not be better to simply start over with a properly designed table?

Comment: Fix your data model!  You shouldn't be storing lists of ingredients in separate columns like that.

Comment: Not my call on that one :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to the below query when condition value matches

`DELETE FROM table WHERE 1 in (I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,R1,R2,R3);`

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can `CONCAT` all the columns that can have the id in it, and see if the resulting string have the sequence "comma-id-comma" in it, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE CONCAT(',' , I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, I8, R1, R2, R3, ',') LIKE '%,1,%'
```

Note the commas at the start and end of the concat, this is needed to check I1 and R3 columns properly.